# Full screen exclusive mode and dual-monitor setup

Tags: java, swing

First I should note that my dual monitors are in custom position rather than the default left-to-right.

I was attempting to create a full-screen exclusive mode game, but in testing I noticed that when I used EXIT_ON_CLOSE (and in System.exit), that the monitor setup would be reset to the default left-to-right.  But when I used DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (and for just a dispose()) it would be perfectly normal when returning to my desktop.  Is this acceptable practice, or is there something I'm missing?

Relevant part:

```
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class FullScreenTest extends JFrame {

    public FullScreenTest() {
        GraphicsDevice screen = GraphicsEnvironment.
              getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        add(new JLabel("Test"));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        screen.setFullScreenWindow(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FullScreenTest test = new FullScreenTest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I used `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` (and for just a dispose()) it would be perfectly normal when returning to my desktop

That is good.  Stick with it.  Many developers use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` when it is entirely unnecessary.

If `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` does not work to end the JRE, it means that other GUI elements are still visible, or other non-daemon threads are running.  In that case, it would generally be better to explicitly end the other threads, or check they can safely be ended.

Comment: Ah, perfect, thank you.  Is there an easy way that I'm missing to check for other elements, or is it alright to just keep track and close manually?

Comment: In testing with an applet or JWS app. it is simple, configure the Java Console to pop up for them, and wait till it closes.  As a more general solution, you might examine the OS applet for viewing running processes.  It should appear as a 'Java' process AFAIR.

Answer (score 2):

- have look at official tutorial [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html)
- [including Examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/example.html)
- [few examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/GraphicsDevicesetFullScreenWindowWindoww.htm) to the tutorials methods about `GraphicsEnvironment` and `GraphicsDevice`

Comment: I have read through it, but I'm a complete novice so I'm not sure I've gotten all of it grasped yet.  However the examples on the tutorial are producing the same effect as mine was as well.

Comment: @DesjardinsM hmmm not sure from your question but Java doesn't supporting fullscreen on dual-monitor

Comment: I wasn't needing it to go fullscreen on both, was just wondering if disposing was alright to do so that I could get my monitor configuration to stay as it was.